# Save byte[] stream as PDF file asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, byte

i have a byte[] stream of data. i need to save this byte in to pdf format in disk.
can any one help

Thanks in advance

Comment: hw cn i mark answers? plz let me know

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to create a `FileStream` object and write the bytes to it with your PDF name and extension.  e.g.

```
byte[] bytes = SomeMethodToGetBytesThatYouDefine();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\somepath.pdf",FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
fs.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: That `FileStream` should be wrapped in a `using` block. Or, even better, use `File.WriteAllBytes` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx):

```
byte[] yourByteArray = GetYourByteArrayFromSomewhere();
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\example.pdf", yourByteArray);
```